# Java Logger wont log into file

Tags: java, java.util.logging, filehandler

I can't make my logger to work.
Inside my code I have these lines :

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName());
log.setUseParentHandlers(false);
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("ex.txt", true);
SimpleFormatter sf = new SimpleFormatter();
fh.setFormatter(sf);
log.addHandler(fh);
log.setLevel(Level.FINE);
```

And later when I get input from user :

```
log.log(Level.FINE,inputString);
```

But all that happens is that fileHandler creates a file ex.txt, but nothing is logged into the file. I am sure that log.log() is being executed.

Comment: Does `fh.flush()` change anything? It shouldn't, since the logger should automatically flush after each record, but it might be worth a try to get closer to the issue.

Comment: @dhke changed nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you only create one FileHandler and ensure that your adjust the level of your FileHandler too.

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName());
private static final FileHandler fh;
static {
    try {
        log.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        fh = new FileHandler("ex.txt", true);
        fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        fh.setLevel(Level.FINE);
        log.addHandler(fh);
        log.setLevel(Level.FINE);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ioe);
    }
}
```

If you still don't see results then you should [print the logger tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882648/logging-not-showing/44888306#44888306) to ensure that the filehander and the loggers are created in the layout you are expecting.

In general, you should should setup a [`logging.properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this simple approach.

```
public static Logger logger;

public static Logger startLogger() {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH-mm-ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String datefor = dateFormat.format(date);

    logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");

    PropertyConfigurator.configure(CLASSPATH + "/" + "log4j.properties");
    Appender appender = null;
    try {

        appender = new FileAppender(new SimpleLayout(), CLASSPATH  + "/log/MyLogFile" + datefor + ".log");
        logger.addAppender(appender);
        appender.setLayout(new SimpleLayout());
    } catch (SecurityException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```