# How to set up logging.properties for HTTPBuilder in Java

Tags: java, groovy, java.util.logging, apache-commons-logging, httpbuilder

I'm trying to get the logs of my connection with HTTP Builder.
I read a lot and heard to set up a configuration file. 
I'm executing my jar from the terminal with this command

```
java -jar -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties Console-0.1.jar
```

And my logging.properties looks like this

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
.level=FINEST
httpclient.wire.header.level=FINEST
org.apache.commons.httpclient.level=FINEST
```

I don't get why it's not working.
Has anyone an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good and pretty easy solution.
Just get the root Logger and set the level before the http builder gets called

```
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger rootLogger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME)
    rootLogger.setLevel(level)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative path to load the `logging.properties`.  Change that to an absolute path and try it again.

Next, attach [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) to your running process:

1. Go to the MBeans tab.
2. Expand nodes `java.util.logging->Logging->Attributes->Operations`.
3. Select `getLoggerLevel` and clear the value of `p0` field.  This is the root logger.
4. Click the `getLoggerLevel` button and see if the level matches what you put in the `logging.properties` file.
5. Go to `java.util.logging->Logging->Attributes->LoggerNames`
6. Double click the `java.lang.String[]` cell in the value column.  If your child logger names from your `logging.properties` are not present then those values in your `logging.properties` are not doing anything.  Correct the child logger names in your `logging.properties.

If none of that works then [print your log tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882648/logging-not-showing/44888306#44888306).