# Why are INFO level logs not showing in Google Cloud Stackdriver? (cloud endpoints Java)

Tags: java.util.logging, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I do not have any exclusions or anything set, but INFO level logs are not showing in Stackdriver from my Cloud Endpoints java code.

NOTE: INFO level logs generated by GAE are logging, such as:

[image]

just not the ones in my code.

I'm using Cloud Endpoints java

Here's a snippet of my Java code

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;

...

LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING,  "testing warning log 1");
LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,  "testing info log");
LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING,  "testing warning log 2");
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try [printing the log configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882648/logging-not-showing/44888306#44888306) and see if there are any handlers installed on the root logger.  You might have to install a ConsoleHandler.  That example won't work directly because you won't be able to access the LogManager in GAE.

Comment: Thank you, turns out the default log level was set to warning in WEB_INF/logging.properties. D'oh!