# java.util.logging won't log to file

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I am struggling with getting `java.util.logging` to log to a file, instead of just to the console in Eclipse.

```
public class TestDefaultConfiguration {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestDefaultConfiguration.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("-- main method starts --");
        logger.info("an info msg");
        logger.warning("a warning msg!");
        logger.severe("a severe msg!");
    }
}
```

Here are the properties:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\lib\logging.properties
```

I edited the default properties file to this:

```
.level= INFO
# default file output is in user's home directory.
#java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = C:/temp/test/MyLogFile2.log

java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
#java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

When I debug the test class, I can see in `logger.manager.props` that these properties are picked up. So far, so good.

Why then is no log-file created in `C:/temp/test/MyLogFile2.log`?

Not sure if I should add in Eclipse configuration VM arguments:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_152/lib/logging.properties"
```

But if I do, it doesn't make a difference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

From your logging.properties, you haven't shown the section where you are attaching the handler to a logger.  This is explained in the file as comments

```
# "handlers" specifies a comma separated list of log Handler 
# classes.  These handlers will be installed during VM startup.
# Note that these classes must be on the system classpath.
# By default we only configure a ConsoleHandler, which will only
# show messages at the INFO and above levels.
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# To also add the FileHandler, use the following line instead.
#handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

[Use the logger debugging code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882648/logging-not-showing) to see if the handler is attached to the root logger.

Add the following line to your properties file:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```