# java.util.logging stops working when I incorporate a library that uses Log4j 2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, java.util.logging

I have an existing application that logs messages using the `java.util.logging` API.  As far as I can see, there are no configuration files for it in the framework, though there is some code to create a file appender.  When I run the application, I get log messages to the console and to a file.

Now, I need to incorporate a library that uses Log4j 2.  When I do so, I lose the console logging from the main application (though log messages still get written to the file appender that is created programmatically).

I imagine that, since the file appender is working in the original application, that I can solve my problem by also programmatically creating a console appender in the main application.  However, I don't know if that's right or a kludge.

**So, my question**: is there anything *general* that I need to know about making `java.util.logging` and Log4j 2 interoperate?  If the original application is not coded properly or according to best practices, I can change it.

Comment: If log4j2 is not a mandatory requirement, you can use SLF4j with JDK logger.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I need to incorporate a library that uses Log4j 2. When I do so, I lose the console logging from the main application (though log messages still get written to the file appender that is created programmatically).

The 
[Log4jBridgeHandler will remove handlers if the install method is called from code](https://www.mvndoc.com/c/de.it-tw/log4j2-Java6-extras/org/apache/logging/log4j/jul/Log4jBridgeHandler.html#install-boolean-java.lang.String-boolean-).    You can always [print the log tree to see what handlers are attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882648/logging-not-showing) or attach a tool like [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#jconsole) to inspect the logger tree with and without the 3rd party lib.

> I imagine that, since the file appender is working in the original application, that I can solve my problem by also programmatically creating a console appender in the main application. However, I don't know if that's right or a kludge.

Programmatic configuration of the logger tree should be done with the [LogManager config option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html):

> A property "config". This property is intended to allow arbitrary configuration code to be run. The property defines a whitespace or comma separated list of class names. A new instance will be created for each named class. The default constructor of each class may execute arbitrary code to update the logging configuration, such as setting logger levels, adding handlers, adding filters, etc.

1. Create a stand alone named class that just installs the handlers in the constructor.
2. Set the `java.util.logging.config.class` system parameter to the name of your class.
3. Otherwise if you have a logging.properties you set `config` to your class name.

> So, my question: is there anything general that I need to know about making java.util.logging and Log4j 2 interoperate? If the original application is not coded properly or according to best practices, I can change it.

The [java.util.logging.LogManager can only see classes on the system class loader](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6448699).  In that case log configuration in code is required to gain access to the correct classloader.

It might be easier to remove all JUL configuration and bridge to Log4j2. You can then leverage the configuration needed through that framework.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer (+1).  It will take me some time to go through this and figure out whether this is actually the best answer for me though.