# Debug logging is not working on specific handler

Tags: java, logging, apache-commons

I'm using a JDK14Logger implementation to apache commons-loggings framework. The debug logs are not appearing, and they appear only when I set the root logger to FINE. My understanding is that log level set to specific handlers should override log level of root logger. However, that is not happening.

```
# The following creates the console handler
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler

# Set the default logging level for the root logger
.level=FINE

# Set the default logging level
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=FINEST

# log level for the "com.rst.example" package


# Set the default formatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

# Specify the location and name of the log file
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=D:/test.log
```

test class:

```
public class Test {
private  Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Test.class.getName());

 static  {
    System.getProperties().setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file","log-config.properties");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //-Djava.util.logging.config.file=src/main/resources/log-config.properties

    Test test =  new Test();

    test.logger.info("info from main");
    test.logger.error("error from main");
    test.logger.fatal("fatal from main");
    System.out.println("is dubug enabled? :" + test.logger.isDebugEnabled());
    test.logger.debug("debug from main");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

All JDK loggers will publish log records to the handlers of the root logger by default. The default level for the ConsoleHandler is [INFO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html).

> My understanding is that log level set to specific handlers should override log level of root logger. However, that is not happening.

It doesn't and it is not. [Use DebugLogging to test your configuration file against the JDK logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882648/logging-not-showing/44888306#44888306).

> The debug logs are not appearing, and they appear only when I set the root logger to FINE.

Output is published to a handler.  Not appearing either means that your handler is not attached, the level is not set to what you expect, or the handler is attached to a child logger that is not on the publishing path.

Modify the DebugLogging class in the linked answer to include your configuration and the apache-commons code that performs logging.  Don't delete the JDK logging code.  The output from that code will direct you to the problem.